# How to print reverse string in nasm?

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16

How to print reverse string in nasm?

I have this code:

```
BITS 16
org 0x7C00
_start:
    xor ax,ax           ; set ax register to 0
    mov ds,ax           ; set data segment(ds) to 0
    mov es,ax           ; set extra segment(es) to 0
    mov bx,0x8000
    mov si,string
    call reverse_print
    jmp $
reverse_print:
    mov ah,0Eh
.rep_pre:
    inc si
    cmp al,0
    je .rep_init
    jmp .rep_pre
.rep_init:
    dec si
    jmp .rep
.rep:
    std
    lodsb
    cmp al,0
    je .done
    int 10h
    jmp .rep
.done:
    cld
    ret
    string db "ABC",0
    times 510-($-$$) db 0   ; Pad remainder of boot sector with 0s
    dw 0xAA55       ; The standard PC boot signature
```

String is:

```
ABC
```

And STDOUT is:

```
A├ⁿ ⌡Θ⯈=♣t
```

Excepted STDOUT:

```
CBA
```

Is way to correct this error that STDOUT is not as excepeted STDOUT?

**EDIT 1**

I extended code and fixed bugs and errors.

Now code looks this:

```
BITS 16
org 0x7C00
_start:
    xor ax,ax           ; set ax register to 0
    mov ds,ax           ; set data segment(ds) to 0
    mov es,ax           ; set extra segment(es) to 0
    mov bx,0x8000
    mov si,string
    call reverse_print
    jmp $
reverse_print:
    mov ah,0Eh
    mov cx,1
.rep_pre:
    inc si
    inc cx
    cmp al,0
    je .rep_init
    jmp .rep_pre
.rep_init:
    inc si
    inc cx
    jmp .rep
.rep:
    std
    lodsb
    dec cx
    cmp al,0
    je .done
    cmp cx,0
    jl .done
    int 10h
    jmp .rep
.done:
    cld
    ret
    string db "ABC",0
    times 510-($-$$) db 0   ; Pad remainder of boot sector with 0s
    dw 0xAA55       ; The standard PC boot signature
```

I corrected some errors using CX register set to 1.

Now STDOUT looks this *as excepted*:

```
CBA
```

Comment: any particular reason, why you didn't try debugger to step over single instructions and check for more details why wrong chars are printed?

Comment: Becuease i'm buliding my own os

Comment: My reverse_print function doesn't worked proprely

Comment: Friendly advice: do not build an OS before you know how to use a debugger.

Comment: BTW the problem is absolutely obvious, if you will debug it... Even by reading the source you should see it immediately, if you would try to comment every group of 2-5 instructions and their purpose in the code and then trying to imagine what the CPU does. But if you are new to assembly, it takes some practice, which is gain exactly by trying to do it yourself. If you have problem to set up bootloader debugger, you can probably switch first into DOS or linux, developing ordinary asm applications which are easier to debug (to find debugger for), or BOCHS emulator is used by some people.

Comment: The `reverse_print` function does 90% of the stuff in your code, so saying "it's not working properly" is same as saying "my bootloader doesn't work properly". (the remaining 10% of code are also not good enough for real-world production OS bootloader, but should work in common test setups used by enthusiast like you). But I agree with Jester, you should first learn basics of x86 assembly, before adding the complexity of bootloader and bare-metal environment on top of that. Try two things now: 1) figure out how to debug your code (it's top priority) 2) comment your code a bit more

Comment: And to fix your code you must: 1) fix your `strlen` part of code to correctly find end of string (it's missing like half of the implementation, I'm just guessing that's what was the original idea of you of that part of code). 2) fix your printing routine to print only the string. It's not zero terminated at front, so your code loading chars until zero will keep printing the memory content going toward beginning of code, until some zero is found accidentally in the instruction opcodes. You need different kind of termination test (length/address) or add zero terminator also ahead of string.

Comment: I guess that printing stops at `cmp al,0` opcode `3C 00` (after `lodsb`), so every instruction after that last `cmp al,0` is printed as character on screen (starting at the first byte of the 'ABC' string, that's that first 'A' letter at the beginning). = once you will figure out how to debug your code, you may want to try this version out to see if I was right, and how to spot such problem while debugging.

Comment: I'm used in line 19 `inc si` instead of `dec si` but stdout is `CBA├ⁿ ⌡Θ⯈=♣t`.

Comment: I used also CX register.

Comment: I have no idea, what lead you to think that changing single line will be enough, your code is broken on several places. I was suggesting you to use debugger and to comment the code, not to randomly change some lines. Random changing code in assembly doesn't work, you always must understand what you have, and how you want to change it. Assembly is not PHP or javascript, where you can keep changing some line until it works by accident... EDIT: your fixed code still doesn't make much sense, it's doing different things than what would be logical, you get correct output only by accident.